# How to concatenate byte in Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

My column is of type `bytea`. It has large data. Storing all data at once can cause Out Of Memory. So I have to concatenate byte one after the other.

To concatenate String we use,

```
UPDATE tbl SET col=CONCAT(col,'test');
```

How to do the same for concatenating byte?

Can it be done using hibernate query?

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-binarystring.html) is saying that for bytea concatenation, you have to use `||` instead

Comment: If storing the data will result in out of memory, wouldn't actually fetching the data result in the same?

Comment: Perhaps it's better to divide by row and then string_agg all bytes when fetching using an common id or equivalent